# In Objective C how can we Blur face in round/circular shape shape?

Tags: ios, objective-c, face-detection, uiblureffect

I am working on iOS app in which i detect face from Image and blurring face , i have already achieved blurring face in rectangular form but what i am required is to Blur face in rounded shape . what i have tried so for is

```
-(void)markAfterFaceDetect:(NSArray *)features
{

    for (CIFaceFeature *f in features)
    {

        CGRect aRect = f.bounds;

        NSLog(@"here is the height of h %f",aRect.size.height);

        // aRect.size.height=aRect.size.height+10;

        aRect.origin.y = self.viewShow.bounds.size.height - aRect.size.height - aRect.origin.y;



        NSLog(@"Height Of the Image Is : == %f",_imageView.image.size.height);
        //self.bounds.size

        rectFaceDetect = aRect;



        UIVisualEffect *blurEffect;
        blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];

        UIVisualEffectView *visualEffectView;
        visualEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];

        visualEffectView.frame = vv.frame;

        //visualEffectView.layer.cornerRadius = visualEffectView.frame.size.height/2;

        visualEffectView.alpha =0.96;

        visualEffectView.tag = markViewTag;
        // [self.imageView addSubview:visualEffectView];


        CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        mask.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:visualEffectView.bounds].CGPath;
        visualEffectView.layer.mask = mask;
    }
}
```

Using this way i have managed to blur face in rounded shape or circular shape but when i take screen shot of the view to save blurred image in application data base its Alpha become 0 and Blurred area becomes visible ,code whichi i am using for taking screenshot is

```
CGRect rect = viewShow.frame;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[viewShow.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

here are the Image before and after screenshots 
[image: after Applying Blur Effects]
[image: After taking Screen shot Alpha becomes 0]

[Now i have used this Category and Achieved this Blur in Rectangular form Image is Attached](https://github.com/Adrian2112/UIImage-BlurredFrame) 
[image]

Now I have Two Questions .
1- How can i blur only face in rounded or circular shape?
2- Why Alpha becomes 0 when i took screenshot programatically .

Desired blur will look like this [image]

Your help will be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

Use [drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:) to capture the on-screen appearance of your view hierarchy.